# How do I get to the Dark World in Super Meat Boy?

Tags: super-meat-boy

I have just completed the game, and it says to try Dark World.  What is that and how do I get there?

Answer (score 7):

The Dark World are just the same levels a few magnitudes more difficult.

To switch between Dark and Light World, you just have to press <kbd>X</kbd> on your gamepad or <kbd>Shift</kbd> on your keyboard in the level select screen (see an example on [Wikia](http://supermeatboy.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_1:_The_Forest?file=CH1lightworldmenu.png)).

Note that the Dark World levels becomes available after you beat the corresponding Light World levels on **A+**. (Thx to shadow for pointing that out)

**Edit:**

To clarify what I mean by "just the same levels a few magnitudes more difficult", I refer you to the [blog of the creators](http://web.archive.org/web/20120118154900/http://supermeatboy.com/13/Why_am_I_so____hard_/) of SMB. (The images are down somehow, so I linked to a web archived version.)

[image: Why am I so hard]

Comment: "Same Levels" is a bit of a misnomer. They're similar, yes, but they can also be wildly different.

Comment: @RavenDreamer With "Same Levels" I meant the layout of the level. The may be a few more saw blades or you might have to go through the level backwards, but the "room" is the same.

Comment: Love that pic! :D however, sometimes it's not true. Sometimes, you are going backwards, or going to the original exit and back (Exploder and Not You Again in the Salt Factory are perfect examples)

Comment: You forgot to mention you need to A+ the level to unlock the respective dark version of it

Comment: @shadow Thx, I'll add it to the answer